# Animate objects of type `dynamic`in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

So i am passing a window to a dll where i receive it as an object of type `dynamic`

```
dynamic theWindow = ...;
```

i need to animate a property of that window, i tried the following:

```
theWindow.BeginAnimation(theWindow.LeftProperty, _leftAnimation);
```

but it doesnt work. so a step i took was to check what if i can access `theWindow.LeftProperty` but i get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Member 'System.Windows.Window.LeftProperty' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at blablabla ...
```

it says to 'qualify it with a type name instead' but i have no idea what it means...

however attributes are accessible and work as expected:

```
theWindow.MaxWidth = theWindow.Width + 108;
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: It is a static member, use `Window.LeftProperty` instead.

Comment: Also, if you *know* the type of the object returned by the other assembly (seems to be `UIElement`), then you should cast it to that type as early as possible and call its methods statically from then on. Get rid of the dynamic stuff if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Window.LeftProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.leftproperty%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a static method and can't be accessed dynamically. You could try

```
theWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, _leftAnimation);
```